# Android Changing activity by onTouch like a book

Tags: java, android

I am a student trying to create tales/story app. I am wanting change the activity when the user swipes right it will go to the next page and when the user swipes left it will go back to the previous page. I have been viewing examples however I am still confused how to do so. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: try reading docs, they are pretty good http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html

Comment: On a side note, I think you should not try to change activity for every page(each activity acting as single page is a bad model). Rather you should change content of the view containing the page text content and animate it. Animation can be a page flip or scroll, anything you like. Just Google for "Android View Animation". Many newbies have difficulty understanding that an activity is more than just a page/screen. As above comments shows better use ViewPager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having one activity for each page, just replace new content on the same activity.

https://github.com/MysticTreeGames/android-page-curl. Page curl.

Page curl with renderscript.

http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/wiki/PageCurl. The link has a video of pagecurl demo.

The source code in available at http://code.google.com/p/renderscript-examples/source/browse/#svn%2Ftrunk%2FPageCurl.

Details regarding renderscript at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/renderscript/index.html.

Here's a video on renderscript talk by Romain guy. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5jz0kSuR2j4.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use page curl effect kind of projects to achieve that like [this](http://androidjayavelu.blogspot.in/2012/08/page-curl-for-android.html) or [this](https://code.google.com/p/android-page-curl/) . The way you think of making use of `activities` might not be a good idea. Because if you just make activities for each page, then it is not guaranteed that they would still exist if you come back as it increases burden on the back stack and the system would automatically destruct the activities if it requires some resources to be allotted for other things. Or you can create your own effects.